# UIA Verify shows no name property for buttons

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I need to automate a workflow and tried to rely on teststack white and UIA Verify to find the buttons in another application.
However when I try to identify the buttons I was greeted with just empty name properties for the controls inside the window I need to control (see attached screenshot).
The controls are apparently of type Custom.

I want to be able to press buttons and enter text into textboxes as well as check a checkbox.

Is there a way? Can I access them via for example an index (e.g. button = third control in window)?

[image: Screenshot of UIA Verify, showing the empty controls]

Edit: As requested a screenshot from inspect.exe
[image: Screenshot of Inspect.exe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind taking a look at those controls with Inspect.exe and posting a screen shot of the properites? You might be able to find another unique property on them to identify it with. Inspect.exe can be found C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\inspect.exe.

With White you wont be able to get a collection of all the buttons but with raw ui-automation you will be able to get a collection of the AutomationElements using [FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example of how to get all controls of a certain type.
[Retrieve Multiple UIItems ByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130961/retrieve-multiple-uiitems-byclassname/21949867#21949867)

**Edit:**
So after looking at the updated image from inspect I am afraid the application you are trying to automate didn't expose their application to ui-automation properly. I was certain that it wasn't exposed properly before but I was hoping they may have accidentally exposed some properties. I have seen this before with some 3rd party controls for VB6. It would be possible using the technique I linked above to get all the controls with a name of "" but then you would have to use the bounding rectangle property to move your mouse to the correct position and click (if that property is reporting the correct position) since I would wagger the [invoke pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753352(v=vs.110).aspx) is not supported. If you have access to the source code you could implement these properties and pattern.

Comment: Thank your for your post, I uploaded a second sreenshot. I could not find a difference in the controls besides the obvious changes in "BoundRectangle" and Legacy.Accessible.State.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code. I am already using a mouse hijacking technique but wanted a more sophisticated method - that is why I had a look at white. Well I guess I just have to stick with it then. Thanks anyway - at least I now know that there is no better way of doing it :)